# Custom comparator for a single property for Angular $filter

Tags: angularjs

First, my reason for creating the custom comparator in the first place is because an attribute on the expression that is an array--such as 'tags'--required the expression to have the values in a particular order and wouldn't match otherwise. (So an expression with tags['a', 'b'] would match ['x', 'a', 'b', 'y'] but not ['x', 'b', 'a', 'y'].)

I've been able to get around this because in Angular's $filter service, it allows you to provide a custom comparator. However, I'm only able to filter based on the attributes type, not the key's value.

I want a custom comparator for only one of the attributes in an object. Is there a way to do that without copying and modifying Angular's source code?

Here is an example of my custom comparator: (found in http://plnkr.co/edit/eFeinQhHTIZrzXBm4srq )

```
$scope.inclusiveFilter = function(expected, actual){
    if(expected && actual){
        console.log(expected, actual);
        if(angular.isArray(expected) && angular.isArray(actual)){
            for(var t in actual){
                if(expected.indexOf(actual[t]) == -1){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
  }
```

In my example the filter on the tags works just fine, but it no longer works on $ to match any property, I am only able to compare attributes based on their type, not their name. So an expression like this could never work:

```
{
    includeThese: ['a', 'b'],
    excludeThese: ['x', 'y']
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this will help you but you can use a key value pair with ng-repeat (key, value) in expression – where key and value can be any user defined identifiers, and expression is the scope expression giving the collection to enumerate.

For example: (name, age) in {'adam':10, 'amalie':12}.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are asking for. I made a plunkr for you with 2 custom filter functions, one that looks for "a" and "b" in order in the list item, and one that looks for "a" and "b" to just be in the tags for that item. Hopefully you can take this and modify it to do what you want. I think for your purposes a custom filter function will be easier to deal with than the custom comparator.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fJ9iPQYyhGxAt00xi0OY

Comment: The comparator `inclusiveComparator` in this example is defined but never used. Is there any example where comparator is used? The Doc is so confusing here.